# How to set rebalanceMode in ignite-sql-api?

Tags: ignite

How to set rebalanceMode in IGNITE-SQL-API? The default is CacheRebalanceMode.ASYNC, I want to set CacheRebalanceMode.SYNC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may specify cache template when issuing CREATE TABLE, and in cache template you may specify rebalance mode.

Please refer to [CREATE TABLE docs](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/create-table).

Comment: Thank you very much!  I can set rebalance mode by taking your advice.